# Crontab Django - не работает задача

Tags: python, django, cron, crontab

Создал такую задачу в файл app/cron.py

```
import datetime
from tasks.models import Task
import json
from channels import Group, Channel
from django.utils import timezone

def deadline_notify():
date_now = timezone.now()
date_now = date_now.replace(second=0, microsecond=0)

tasks = Task.objects.filter(created_date=date_now)

Group("notify").send({
    "text": json.dumps({
        "count": tasks.count()
    })
})

text_file = open("Output.txt", "w")

text_file.write("Purchase Amount: " + date_now.isoformat() )

text_file.close()

if tasks.count() != 0:
    for item in tasks:
        Group("notify").send({
            "text": json.dumps({
                "type": 'task.deadline',
                "id": item.doer_id,
                "task_id": item.task_id,
                "content": item.description
            })
        })
```

Запускаю задачу как в туториале

```
python manage.py crontab add
python manage.py crontab run
```

Задача не выполняется, хотя светиться при выполнении команды crontab -l

```
(env) root@back-sales:~/web/ordamed-pure-crm/crm# crontab -l
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /root/web/ordamed-pure-crm/crm/manage.pycrontab run 1e77979da5ee47061c1dc8e450485345 # django-cronjobs for crm
```

Время выполнения - */1 * * * *.

В чем проблема?

Comment: Ну так покажите нам вывод crontab -l и попутно manage.py crontab show, че прячете-то)

Comment: @andreymal 
(env) root@back-sales:~/web/ordamed-pure-crm/crm# crontab -l
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /root/web/ordamed-pure-crm/crm/manage.py crontab run 1e77979da5ee47061c1dc8e450485345 # django-cronjobs for crm

Comment: @andreymal
Вот вывод через crontab -l